# Delete Rows in Pandas Dataframe by Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with states and counties but some of the counties are just the state as a whole. I'm trying to iterate through line by line to delete rows in which the df['STNAME'] == df['COUNTY'].

```
    SUMLEV  REGION  DIVISION    STATE   COUNTY  STNAME  CTYNAME CENSUS2010POP   ESTIMATESBASE2010   POPESTIMATE2010 ... RDOMESTICMIG2011    RDOMESTICMIG2012    RDOMESTICMIG2013    RDOMESTICMIG2014    RDOMESTICMIG2015    RNETMIG2011 RNETMIG2012 RNETMIG2013 RNETMIG2014 RNETMIG2015
0   40  3   6   1   0   Alabama Alabama 4779736 4780127 4785161 ... 0.002295    -0.193196   0.381066    0.582002    -0.467369   1.030015    0.826644    1.383282    1.724718    0.712594
1   50  3   6   1   1   Alabama Autauga County  54571   54571   54660   ... 7.242091    -2.915927   -3.012349   2.265971    -2.530799   7.606016    -2.626146   -2.722002   2.592270    -2.187333
2   50  3   6   1   3   Alabama Baldwin County  182265  182265  183193  ... 14.832960   17.647293   21.845705   19.243287   17.197872   15.844176   18.559627   22.727626   20.317142   18.293499
```

I tried a for loop with iterrows but it's not giving me an output.

```
for rows in df.iterrows():
     if ['STNAME'] == ['CTYNAME']:
          df.drop(axis=0)
          print(census_df)
```

Again, I want to iterate through the rows and delete rows in which the df.['STNAME'] == df['COUNTY'].

Comment: `df = df[~( df.['STNAME'] == df['COUNTY'])]`

Comment: Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @QuangHoang's answer is correct, but if you wanted to do the loop, `.itertuples` is easier to work with: 
for rows in df.itertuples():
     if df.STNAME == df.CTYNAME:
          df.drop(axis=0)
          print(census_df)

Comment: @QuangHoang what is that format/method called so I can learn how to create my own code like that?

Comment: That’s [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you!